# drop down list compatibility issue between Excel 2007 and Excel 2010

Tags: excel

I prepared a spreadsheet where I used the drop down list command in several cells (data validation, list).  I needed to provide two versions of the same spreadsheet: one saved as Excel 2007 file, and the other one as Excel 2010 file.

If I open the Excel 2007 file with Excel 2010, in the cells where I inserted the drop down list, the reference to the cells that contain the list is somehow changed and the drop down list shows the wrong data.

For example, if I specify to use as the data in the list the values of cells C20:C25, when I open the file with Excel 2010 the cells are changed to D15:D20.  I did not find a trend in the "shifting" of the referenced cells.

How do I prevent this without using Excel 2007 for the 2007 file only and Excel 2010 for the 2010 file only?

Answer (score 6):

I have found a workaround that works for me.

If this is your original dropdown box formula:
=Sheet2!A1:A5

Then change it to:
=INDIRECT("Sheet2!A1:A5")

For me, this stops it removing the dropdown when opening in Excel 2007 after saving in Excel 2010.  I found this out accidentally because I needed INDIRECT to define my dropdown range, as it varied.

Jeremy

Comment: Thanks!! Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=150080

> "If your dropdown is a data validation list and you have used a list on another sheet as the
>   source, then you need to do what Tayt said, since versions pre-2010 cannot refer directly to
>   a range on another sheet and the validation will simply disappear."

That solved my problem; hopefully it'll solve yours.

Comment: *"do what Tayt said"* what did Tayt say? You're missing some information in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a 2007 file with 2010, saving it and closing it.  Perhaps 2010 is automatically converting your file to the 2010 format.
Have you tried intentionally telling 2010 to save your file in the 2007 format?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by having both Excel 2007 and 2010 installed.In Excel 2010 I selected the cell that should have contained the dropdown-list and then pressed data validation from the data tab. I just copied the values in excell 2007 and saved.

If you find the sheet to be protected, you can use this solution : http://mcgimpsey.com/excel/removepwords.html

Hope it helps