# How to create drop down list in excel sheet ?

Tags: php, excel

I wants to create excel sheet that should contain drop down list with four options. i have tried it using Data -> Validity -> List option. but if i am sending this excel sheet after saving to another pc drop down list does not show at all.

it should be work on all excel software like MS excel, Open Office, Libra office.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7715684/drop-down-list-compatibility-issue-between-excel-2007-and-excel-2010

Comment: Thanks for review Tom. But this question asking about excel 7 to excel 10 compatibility.  my consideration is all excel software like open office and libra office

Comment: Actually i need to create one excel sheet with drop down and upload it to my server so if any user download with their any excel software it should show drop down.